# how to transfer group node between projects including keyframes

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, video-sequence-editor, keyframes, project

Can I get a bit of help on how to transfer group node between projects including keyframes?
I have managed to do it with grouping nodes > save as > append from new project.
But I didn't get the keyframes
Thanks
Giaco